# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching transformation(::Scene)

Tags: julia, makie.jl, agents.jl

I have this weird issue since this morning, when i try to use any Agent_plotting method
**ex:abmplot,abmexploration,abmvideo** from The **Agents.jl, Interactive dynamics and Makie** Packages.
The code and package version haven't been updated during the weekend and the issue appeared this morning.I since have removed these libraries, updated and even downgraded the versions but nothing seems to do the trick.
I've been trying to simplify the code but nothing works : abmexploration(model) returns the same error.
Has One of these libraries been changed and all three are impacted?
Thank your for your help guys,
have a nice day.

Comment: perhaps upgrade all dependencies?

Comment: Hi mate thanks for answering. I have tried upgrading the packages and downgrading the versions too but nothing works :/ I still have the same errors

Comment: Could you post the versions of the packages you're using?  That might provide a clearer picture.